# C - isgraph() function

Tags: c

Does anyone know how the `isgraph()` function works in C? I understand its use and results, but the code behind it is what I'm interested in.

For example, does it look at only the `char` value of it and compare it to the ASCII table? Or does it actually check to see if it can be displayed? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code behind the `isgraph()` function varies by platform (or, more precisely, by implementation).  One common technique is to use an initialized array of bit-fields, one per character in the (single-byte) codeset plus EOF (which has to be accepted by the functions), and then selecting the relevant bit.  This allows for a simple implementation as a macro which is safe (only evaluates its argument once) and as a simple (possibly inline) function.

```
#define isgraph(x) (__charmap[(x)+1]&__PRINT)
```

where `__charmap` and `__PRINT` are names reserved for the implementation.  The `+1` part deals with the common situation where `EOF` is `-1`.

---

According to the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999):

> ### §7.4.1.6 The isgraph function
>
> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <ctype.h>
> int isgraph(int c);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The isgraph function tests for any printing character except space (' ').

And:

> ### §7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`
>
> ¶1 The header  declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>   characters.<sup>166)</sup> In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ¶2 The behavior of these functions is affected by the current locale. Those functions that
>   have locale-specific aspects only when not in the "C" locale are noted below.
>
> ¶3 The term printing character refers to a member of a locale-specific set of characters, each
>   of which occupies one printing position on a display device; the term control character
>   refers to a member of a locale-specific set of characters that are not printing
>   characters.<sup>167)</sup> All letters and digits are printing characters.
>
> <sup>166)</sup> See ‘‘future library directions’’ (7.26.2).
>
> <sup>167)</sup> In an implementation that uses the seven-bit US ASCII character set, the printing characters are those
>   whose values lie from 0x20 (space) through 0x7E (tilde); the control characters are those whose
>   values lie from 0 (NUL) through 0x1F (US), and the character 0x7F (DEL).

Answer (score 2):

It's called isgraph, not isGraph (and char, not Char), and the POSIX Programmer's Manual says

> The isgraph() function shall test
>   whether c is a character of class
>   graph in the program's current locale;
>   see the Base Definitions volume of
>   IEEE Std 1003.1-2001,
>          Chapter 7, Locale.

So yes, it looks it up in a table (or equivalent code). It can't check whether it can actually be displayed, since that would vary depending upon the output device, many of which can display chars in addition to those for which isgraph returns true.

Comment: isgraph is part of the ISO standard, there's little need to refer to POSIX.

Comment: @The ISO standard provides minimal requirements on an implementation. POSIX is often more useful for actual implementations.

Answer (score 0):

`isgraph` checks for "printable" characters, but the definition of "printable" can vary depending on your locale.  Your locale may use characters that aren't in the ASCII table.  Internally, it's most likely either a table lookup, a range-based test (`(x >= 'a') && (x <= 'z')`, etc), or a combination of both.  Different implementations may do it slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

The isgraph() macro only looks at the ASCII table, or your location/country/providence/planet/galaxy's version of the ASCII table.

Here's a test code [Counting Words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899856/2548100), which found you can increase performance by writing your own version, which initializes a bool array[256] using isgraph(). There are  benchmark results with the code.

Since bool variables/arrays are actually BYTEs, not bits, you can do even better, in terms of memory efficiency, if you use a bit array, and test that. It happily takes up only 32 bytes. That's almost certainly going to get cashed on any general-purpose modern processor.

Importantly, if you want a slightly different test than the standard ones provided here [(see graphic depiction of character tests)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint), you are free to change the initialization provided by the standard test to include your own exceptions.

[image: Truth table for various character test macros]

Comment: It only looks at the ASCII table on ASCII-based systems. There are still systems that use EBCDIC, for example.

Comment: @KeithThompson, that seems reasonable Keith. Would you happen to have a graph of the various char tests like the one I just implanted above? It might prove helpful, and my COBOL days are behind me, so I don't have that graphic available to me. TVMIA if so! :)

Comment: It looks like EBCDIC is a bloody mess, and no simple BYTE integer range checks are going to do. If there's an equivalent of the above isxxxxxxx macros in those environments, my guess is they're highly valued. On the other hand, what masochistic sod would endure such an environment? :-O  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Comment: I don't see the problem. Typical `<ctype.h>` implementations for ASCII use a lookup table, one byte per entry, with each bit representing one of the attributes. There's no reason the same approach wouldn't work just as well for EBCDIC.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I agree, it will work just as well in EBCDIC. My point was, whereas I can perform an isprint() as a two-sided test as (c < 32 || c > 126), no such niceties will be available in EBCDIC, so macros such as isprint() will be more valuable. If you study the ASCII table above, it's striking how well ordered it is.

Comment: Ah, so you're comparing the usefulness of `isprint` to the alternative of hard-coded (and non-portable) tests like `(c >= 32 && c <= 126)` (`isprint(' ')` is true). I misunderstood your point. But whether you're using ASCII, EBCDIC, or Sumerian cuneiform, I don't see much point in *not* using `<ctype.h>`, so it didn't occur to me to make the comparison.

Comment: @KeithThompson, me either, but I've been hacking my way into ZeroMQ. If you want a good belly laugh, take a look at zhelpers.h, lines 85-90. Wrong on so many levels it's pathetic. Kind of proves your point. (pretty sure I don't want to print ASCII 127 to putty, or it's just going to erase the character before it) Wrong, wrong, wrong. The hits just keep on coming. lololol