# software testing for program of counting words in a stream of charatcers

Tags: c

I have done a program where input given should be stream of characters and program counts the
non-whitespace characters and words. word is defined as the stream of characters which are separated by a whitespace character. so here is the program..

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include<iso646.h>

int main(void)  
{   unsigned long int wordcount = 0,charcount = 0, count=1;
    int ch;
    bool flag, prev;



    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) 
      {   if(isgraph(ch))
              flag=true;
          else
              flag=false;

          if(flag)
             charcount++;

          if(count ==1)
             prev = flag;

        if(count != 1)
           {   if(prev and (not flag))
                  wordcount++;
               prev = flag;
           }

          count++;
      }

    if((ch == EOF) and flag)
          wordcount++;

   printf("\nnumber of words counted are %lu \n", wordcount);
   printf("\nnumber of characters counted are %lu \n", charcount);



   return 0;

}
```

now I have checked this program on simple sentences. But just for practice, I want to do
detailed software testing on this. So how can I do that ? Do I just give more number of sentences ? I tried to give few paragraphs from some novels I found at project gutenberg. 
what else I can do here ? Also can I improve the efficiency of this program ?

Comment: don't name variables "flag"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various basic tests to do:

1. Empty file
2. File with one blank only
3. File with one non-blank only
4. File with one blank and one non-blank
5. File with one non-blank and one blank
6. File with multiple blanks only
7. File with multiple non-blanks only
8. File with multiple blanks followed by non-blanks

And so it goes on...this is boundary testing; making sure that the code works correctly on boundary conditions.

Your assignment of the value from `getchar()` to an `unsigned long int` (now fixed in the question) is unusual.  Since the return value is positive for a regular character and negative (EOF) for end-of-file or error, it is normal to assign it to a signed plain `int`.

Your test `ch == EOF` after the loop is redundant; the only way out of the loop is when the condition is true.

Using `<iso646.h>` and the (macros) keywords `and` and `not` is unusual too.

Most commonly, people do not put code on the same line as the open brace of a block.

You could increment `charcount` in the `if` block where you set `flag = true;`.  You could use an `else` block instead of `if (count != 1)`.  In fact, AFAICT, your code:

```
if(count ==1)
    prev = flag;

if(count != 1)
    {   if(prev and (not flag))
            wordcount++;
        prev = flag;
    }
```

could be written as:

```
if (count > 1 and prev and (not flag))
    wordcount++;
prev = flag;
```

The description 'number of characters counted' isn't strictly accurate; it is the number of graphical (non-blank, non-control) characters that you're reporting.  That's probably on the hyper-nitpicking end of the fussiness scale, though (along with the observation that the 'number of words' is a singular quantity and it should be 'is' rather than 'are').

It is slightly unusual to start your `count` at 1 rather than zero.  It seems to record 'one more than the number of raw characters read into the program', which is an unusual quantity to record.  More  normally, you'd initialize it to 0 too, and modify the test I rewrote to read:

```
if (count != 0 and prev and (not flag))
```

(You can use `count != 0` or `count > 0`; for an unsigned value, the terms are equivalent.)

You might be able to simplify your conditionals by initializing `prev` appropriately (probably to `false`).

Comment: Excellent write-up.  I'd like to add that if and when bugs are encountered in the code, that will dictate what further test methods are needed.  Write the test to reproduce the bug, then use the test to ensure you've actually fixed it.

Comment: Jonathan.. very good comment... actually I have `ch` as `int` in my code. While writing here I made mistake. I have edited that. I included `iso646.h` so that I could use keywords like `not` , `and` and so on ..like in python.  I just hacked this program quickly...

Comment: @issacnewton, `getchar` returns an int; so no, that wasn't a mistake and thus didn't need fixing. (And by the way Jonathan Leffler already said so.)
http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/ ;
If you want to read more than just one character - take a look at fgets.

Comment: Jonathan , you suggested that my test `ch == EOF` after the loop is redundant. But I think its important. try running this program for the input `hi jonathan` from the keyboard and then terminate the process with Ctrl+D to invoke EOF on unix based machines. You will see that it will count only one word and not two. So if we don't include this `ch == EOF` condition, then one word is counted less in special circumstances where non-whitespace character precedes immediately to EOF

Comment: Hi Jonathan, just ran all the tests suggested by you. I only had problem with the case of empty file. I rectified it by intialising `flag` variable to `false`. Now all the cases work very well..

Answer (score 0):

Get in the habit of putting the constant you're testing for on the left, as in

while (EOF != (ch = getchar()))

...as this will save you from spending countless hours, just when you can least afford a setback, when you accidentally type = when you mean ==. Since you can't assign a variable to a constant, the compiler will flag your error, and save your butt.

In my experience, once you get used to reading this kind of code, you'll find it's much faster to find what is being tested for when located right next to the if(, while(, than hunting for it somewhere in the body of the test. This is especially true if you have a long list of tests, like opening files, sockets, etc, and then allocating memory via malloc() to hold file data.

**PS: After some examination, there are a few basic CS 101 things worth mentioning...**

1st, you have a classic case here - in this case because you have a requirement to look behind one character, even on the 1st pass through the while() loop - for seeding a while() loop. The solution is to set up the while() loop with a simple if() block that does a single pass through the same logic as that of the while() loop. (FYI, a while() is an infinite set of if()s with a termination condition)

The proper way to do this is as shown. The payoff is being able to toss out all the if() tests attendant with checking to see if this is the first pass through the while() loop every single time through that loop. The 1st pass here is handled by the if() test that precedes the while() loop.

2nd, I found your variable names to be uninformative. That doesn't mean they were "wrong", but it's likely someone trying to maintain your code would struggle as well. In my experience, as you understand a piece of code better, the variable names get better and better. Use that as a litmus test for whether you understand the problem, have a good solution, and know why.

3rd, when you find yourself initializing a variable in main() to 1, it should raise a flag in your mind about correct flow control, as what is now PassKnt was, being set to 1. Also, generally, you want to increment a loop counter at the END of the loop/if/while, not the beginning of it. Again, this should cause you to question your logic.

**NOTE:** Notepad, by default, saves in unicode format. If using Notepad to create test files for this program, be sure to save in **ANSI** format.

I left it in, because it makes the program easier to understand, but IsGraphFlg is unnecessary here. Instead of assigning IsGraphFlg to WasGraphFlg at the bottom of the loop, it can be done at the bottom of both the top and bottom halves of the if-else block, as the contexts supply the same info as the IsGraphFlag.

```
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(pFile)))  {
        if(isgraph(ch)) {
            IsGraphFlg=true;
            charcount++;
        }   else    {   // this char is whitespace, last char was part of a word
            IsGraphFlg=false;
            if(WasGraphFlg) {
                wordcount++;
            }
        }
        WasGraphFlg = IsGraphFlg;
        PassKnt++;
    }
```

You might also notice that PassKnt serves no purpose now either, and is no longer needed.

It's been suggested that isgraph() is optimal, but when I created a bool array and initialized it using isgraph(), the code ran (out of a memory buffer, which is ~ 10X as fast as from a file on this Dell XPS 8500) in just under 2/3rds of the time - 9.25 clocks instead of 14.75 per character. This is a completely optional optimization - although a significant one.

```
bool    IsGph[256];
for(i=0; i<sizeof(IsGph); i++)  {
    IsGph[i] = isgraph((unsigned char)i);
}
```

In use, if(isgraph(i)) is replaced by if(IsGph[i]) in the main character and word counting loop.

**Code updated 12/30/2012**

```
// Word_Counter.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <locale>

#define UCHAR unsigned char
#define dbl   double
#define LLONG __int64

#define PROCESSOR_HZ ((LLONG) 3400000000)
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
//
//  function prototypes
FILE *OpenFiles (int *FileSz, char *FileName);
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
FILE *OpenFiles (int *FileSz, char *FileName)   {
    FILE *pFile=NULL;
    if (NULL == (pFile = fopen ((char *)FileName, "r+t" ))) {
        printf ( "Can't open %s\n", FileName );
        return NULL;
    }   else    {
        fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_END);
        *FileSz = ftell(pFile);
        rewind(pFile);
        printf("\nFile size is %i", *FileSz);
        return pFile;
    }
 }
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[])  {
bool    IsGph[256];
UCHAR   *p, *pBuff=NULL;
int     WrdKnt=0,CharKnt=0;
int     i, j, FileSz, LoopKnt=3500;
time_t  Etime=0,start=0, Eclocks=0;
FILE    *pFile=NULL;
bool    WasGraphFlg=false;

    //  Initialize boolean array to detect printable characters
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(IsGph); i++)  {
        IsGph[i] = isgraph((unsigned char)i);
    }
    if(NULL == (pFile = OpenFiles(&FileSz, (char *)argv[1])))   {
        return 0;
    }
   // --- Process out of buffer, not stdin -------------------------------
    pBuff = (unsigned char *)calloc(FileSz,  sizeof(char));
    fread(pBuff, sizeof(char), FileSz, pFile);
    start = clock();
    for(i=LoopKnt; i; i--)  {
        p= pBuff;
        CharKnt=0;
        WrdKnt=0;
        for(j=FileSz; j; j--)   {
            if(IsGph[*p++]) {
                CharKnt++;
                WasGraphFlg = true;
            }   else    {           // this char is whitespace, and
                if(WasGraphFlg) {   // last char was part of word ?
                    WrdKnt++;
                }
                WasGraphFlg = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Etime  = clock() - start;
    Eclocks= Etime * PROCESSOR_HZ/(LLONG) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nElapsed time for %10i loops was %10i milliseconds",
                    LoopKnt, Etime);
    printf("\nCPU cycles consumed per char were %2f\n", 
                    (dbl)Eclocks/(dbl)((LLONG)FileSz*(LLONG)LoopKnt));
    printf("\n%i words counted per loop", WrdKnt);
    printf("\n%i chars counted per loop\n", CharKnt);
    getchar();
    return _fcloseall();
    free(pBuff);
}
```

If you're having problems with your command line arguement specifying a file name, under "Projects->Properties->Configuration Properties->General" in Visual Studio, change "Unicode" to the badly mislabled "Multi-Byte" character set. You can always look at argv[1]'s memory in the debugger to find out what's actually in argv[].

Comment: It is very unlikely that `isgraph()` is 'searching' anything.  The standard implementation of the `isxxxxx()` macros uses an array indexed by character number (or character number plus one to fit EOF, -1, in too), and does bitwise masking operations: `#define isgraph(c) (_Ctypes[(c)+1]&_GRAPH)` or something similar.

Comment: The web site http://cppreference.com/ doesn't always win high marks for accuracy. That page is an illustration of why. It talks about 'any graphical character specific to the current C locale'. That's very sloppy. There's the current locale, and there's the C locale, and they are not necessarily the same. Typically (but not on EBCDIC machines), the ASCII character set is used, and the standard C characters are in the lower 127 bytes. However, in other locales (or codesets), that is not guaranteed.  The `isgraph()` function must handle every possible `unsigned char` plus EOF as argument values.

Comment: thanks RocketRoy for this input. its good suggestion that when testing conditions, constant should be put to the left. will keep that in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the heads-up. Will keep in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I thought you might find the benchmark at the bottom interesting or even useful. The performance gain would be greater if several character attributes were being interrogated for, as the bool IsGph[] could be the or of those flags. I have to admit, I was surprised it ran in 2/3rds of the time.